# Выбор модели машинного обучения

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras, xgboost

Прошу помощи, есть задача предсказать лучшую цену, которую дадут в ходе аукциона

Цена зависит как от параметров объекта продажи, так и от параметров участников аукциона

У каждого участника аукциона есть, для примера, индекс аффинитивности в конкретной ценовой категории, т.е. насколько он склонен давать хорошие цены в этой категории

Если для каждого аукциона усреднять индексы всех участников, то смысл индекса теряется. Мы уже не увидим, что участвует кто-то очень аффинитивный.

Брать максимальное значение каждого индекса тоже не совсем правильно, ибо в итоге влияет наверное какая-то комбинация индексов, а так же индексы ближайшего конкурента

Если развернуть 10 признаков 10 участников, и получить 100 признаков, нужно каким-то образом отсортировать участников. И модель не поймет, что первые 10 признаков относятся к одному участнику.

Предсказывать цену, которую даст каждый из участников, не вариант, потому что не раскрывается весь потенциал участников, если один из участников сильно увеличил ставку. Остальные сразу сдаются

С нейросетями знаком плохо, но там можно подавать на вход в качестве одного объекта тензор любой размерности.

Помогут ли в моем случае нейросети? Если да, подскажите, какую универсальную архитектуру выбрать для регрессии? С какими слоями ознакомиться в первую очередь, помимо dense, чтобы получить хорошее качество?
Правильно ли, если я один объект буду представлять в виде матрицы 50*10, где 10 - кол-во участников, а 50 - кол-во признаков, 40 из которых описывают объект и будут повторяться 10 раз. Остальные 10 признаков описывают участника, если участников меньше 10, то подставлять медианные значения признаков, или нули

Или все же, может, у меня бревно в глазу, и я не вижу очевидного решения по аггрегации признаков?

Comment: если бы целевые признаки не влияли друг на друга, то такая задача называлась бы `Multi-Target Regression` и в сети много примеров решений таких задач. А вот в случае зависимости выходных/целевых столбцов друг от друга - это уже совсем другая задача. Здесь также будет играть роль в какой последовательности участники предлагают свою цену. Может стоит подумать как преобразовать эти данные в `time-series`?

Comment: @MaxU, если я правильно вас понял, приведение к time-series приведет к тому, что модель будет предсказывать цену уже в ходе аукциона. Мне же нужно предсказать цену до начала аукциона. "С таким-то составом участников цена будет такая"

Comment: В таком случае это простая задача: Multi-Target Regression

Comment: не очень понял. у меня на выходе должен быть скаляр для одного объекта. а на входе матрица. multi-input regression)
предсказывать конечную ставку каждого участника плохая идея, потому что в обучающей выборке нет истинных значений. максимальная ставка любого участника, кроме выигравшего, почти всегда могла бы быть больше, если бы его не перебили сразу большой ставкой

Comment: вы можете выложить обучающую выборку (анонимизированную) на какой-нибудь файлообменник?